# Binding event handlers to the templated hyperlink

Tags: wpf, microsoft-metro

I created a templated hyperlinkbutton in wpf (windows 8 metro app):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
<HyperlinkButton>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition To="PointerOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>                
        </VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HyperlinkForegroundBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FF011751"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <ContentPresenter Content={TemplateBinding Content}>
        <ContentPresenter.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="HyperlinkForegroundBrush" Color="3FFB20404"/>
        </ContentPresenter.Foreground>
    </ContentPresenter>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

and this is the hyperlinkbutton::

```
<HyerlinkButton Style={StaticResource MainPageLinkStyle} x:Name="MoreDetailsHyperlinkButton" Content="More..." Click="MoreDetailsHyperlinkButton_Click"/>
```

The style MainPageLinkStyle refers to the above style mentioned.

Problem: The click of the hyperlinkbutton doesn't gets executed.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Instead of hyperlinkbutton's click event, when I use PointerPressed event, the mouse right click triggers this event,but not the mouse left click....Seems strange to me.

Comment: Is this referring to WPF or Metro XAML? They're not the same framework.

Comment: John, is this possible in WPF? May be I can relate it with Metro XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here's the modified markup:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
<**Border**>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition To="PointerOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>                
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HyperlinkForegroundBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FF011751"/>
                    </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <ContentPresenter Content={TemplateBinding Content}>
            <ContentPresenter.Foreground>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="HyperlinkForegroundBrush" Color="3FFB20404"/>
            </ContentPresenter.Foreground>
        </ContentPresenter>
</**Border**>
```

As highlighted in the markup,  I need to use Border class instead of Hyperlink. I am not able to understand why, but this seems to be a possible solution working for me.